# TCP read a file and send to the client in java

Tags: java, sockets, methods, tcp

Let me explain my work.

I have to send a file from server to client. In server I accepted the connection from the client and not closed the connection. Now I have to send the data as streams to the client.

Now I have selected a content and wrote in a file in method.

I have send method in which I have to send the file in inputstreams to the client. How to send?

```
     public static void main(String args[]) 
{



    int port=5000;
    while(true)
    {
       try

    {
    ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port+10);

    System.out.println("CLIENT A IS CONNECTED");

    ser.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
       try
    {
    ServerSocket ser1=new ServerSocket(port+20);

    ser1.accept();

    System.out.println("CLIENT B IS CONNECTED");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
       try
    {
    ServerSocket ser2=new ServerSocket(port+30);

    ser2.accept();

    System.out.println("CLIENT C IS CONNECTED");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
       try
    {
    ServerSocket ser3=new ServerSocket(port+40);

    ser3.accept();

    System.out.println("CLIENT D IS CONNECTED");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    }
}
```

In main method I accepted All the client request.

```
       private void jButton1ActionPerformed1(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) //sendbutton

    {
     try
     {
     FileReader buf=new FileReader("e:\\input.txt");

     int port= // the port of client which I selected to send the data
     try
     {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket ser=new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket soc=ser.accept();
        BufferedReader toclient=new BufferedReader(buf);
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println(dos.toString());

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();




    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println(e);
     }

    }
```

Now my question is I already opened the ports and the connection is established in the main method. I have to send the data from server to client by selecting to which client should receive the data in sendbutton method. I am confused how to check or pass the socket object serv1 to the send method?.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to accomplish. The short code you've provided does not even compile (there is no method `accept` in `Socket`; it belongs to `ServerSocket`). It appears you need nothing more than a simple server-client communication, for which there are tons of tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+socket+communication

Comment: I edited the code. @Dejan. please help

Comment: This code is nonsense. Calling accept() without saving the result is nonsense. The question is nonsense. Read a networking tutorial and try again.

Comment: @EJP what is nonsense with this code?

Comment: First, you client is connecting to all the four servers. More-over there is no accept method for your servers. Secondly, in main method again you have a new ServerSocket been created. The code is totally wrong.

Comment: @asifsid88  Thats what I tried and I couldn't find any nice solution. I know my code is wrong and I want to know how to overcome this problem? I explained detail in my question. help me to find a quick solution. And 4 clients is connecting to a server

Answer (score 0):

below is the sample server code (please add corresponding import statements and your logic)

```
class SampleServer
{
    private int port;
    private ArrayList clientList;   

    public SampleServer()
    {
        this.port = 4444;
    }

    public SampleServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void startServer()
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(this.port);
        Socket soc;
        while(true)
        {
            soc = ss.accept();
            clientList.add(soc);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getClientList()
    {
        return clientList;
    }
}
```

Below is the sample main method (take this as a reference and create your own code)

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //Create a server
        //Server has to be only one and multiple clients can connect it
        SampleServer server = new SampleServer(5555);
        server.startServer();

        //Creating one client
        Socket soc = new Socket("localhost", 5555);

        //Similarly create n-number of clients and connect to the same port as that of server

        //server.getClientList(); will help you get the list of the clients connected to the server
    }
}
```